# How to get DataTable in Mono Data SQL

Tags: database, sqlite, mono

I write a function that gets the list of object in my database

```
public List<T> GetList<T>() where T: new()
{
    IDbCommand dbCmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + typeof(T).FullName;
    IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

    List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        T obj = new T();
        foreach(var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, row[prop.Name], null);
        }
        returnList.Add(obj);
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

However forexamle if I run this for my Weapon class which has

```
public int ID { get; set;}
public int Cost { get; set; }
public int Power { get; set; }
public int Distance { get; set; }
```

I get 25 columns and I if run for Monster class I got same 25 columns which goes by "ColumnName", "ColumnOrdinal", "ColumnSize", "NumericPrecision" etc...

So that I cannot set my "Cost" property since this dataset does not has the Cost column name.

How can I get SchemaTable correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem without using SchemaTable

```
public List<T> GetList<T>() where T: new()
{
    IDbCommand dbCmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
    dbCmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", typeof(T).FullName);
    IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        T obj = new T();
        foreach(var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(reader[prop.Name], prop.PropertyType), null);
        }
        returnList.Add(obj);
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

This script gets all the items in given table successfully.